# how to create links on toggle slide bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following toggle slide bar code and I want to create links for each way of label. If is left side is going on one page and if it is right side is going to other page.

This is my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="toggle">    
            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="toggle" name="check" />
            <label for="toggle"></label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS

```
body {
    background: #555;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle {
    width: 93px;
    height: 34px;
    background: url(long-bar.png);
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    }

.toggle label {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 81px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
}

.toggle label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 81px;
    background: url(bit.png);
    left: -20px;
    top: -23px;

    }

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 54px;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background: url(bit.png);
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Think you have something like this http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/158491/122388823/stock-vector-ui-kit-elements-slider-toggle-in-chrome-122388823.jpg but I don't want with on or off like this. I want as "ON" to show latest pictures page and if is "OFF" to show newest page so I need to know where and how to put that <a href="#">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jQuery function to watch the toggle, and if it becomes "checked" then redirect to new page:

```
$("#toggle").on("change",function(){
    $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.prop("checked") == true ) {
        window.location = "http://example.com/link1";   
    } else {
        window.location = "http://example.com/link2";
    }
});
```